# NSTimer leaking memory (CFArray?)

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nstimer

When testing my app for memory leaks I discovered that whenever I start NSTimer with an interval, it shows that CFArray (store-deque) and CFArray (mutable-variable) keeps growing in size. In my actual app Malloc 16 and Malloc 32 etc increases in size alongside with the CFArray.

Question: how do I stop this "leak"?

code: .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSTimer *timerClock;
    int timer;
}
@end
```

code: .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    timer = 0;
    timerClock = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(counter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)counter
{

}
@end
```

Comment: post `- (void)counter` code. may be that one is causing leak

Comment: @Rob: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: actually in my test app, the `- (void)counter` method is empty like above. Just to point out that NSTimer is leaking in my test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you seeing this when you dismiss your view controller? I ask this because a repeating `NSTimer` keeps a strong reference to its `target` and if you don't `invalidate` the timer when you dismiss the view controller, you'll leak both the timer and the controller itself because you will have a strong reference cycle (a.k.a. a [retain cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810)) between the controller and the `NSTimer`.

By the way don't try to `invalidate` in the controller's `dealloc` method, because with the strong reference cycle, `dealloc` will never get called. Often people will `invalidate` in `viewDidDisappear`. And, clearly, if you're going to `invalidate` your timer in `viewDidDisappear`, you probably should be creating it in `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`, to make sure you balance your creation of the timer with its `invalidate` calls.

Comment: no, i see this after i launch my app. I also tried it with attaching the NSTimer to a button to check if it was indeed the timer leaking and it was. The code in the OP is pretty much all the code in my test app and its leaking. Could it be an ARC thing?

Comment: Are you seeing this in the `Leaks` instrument, or in the `allocations` instrument? If the latter, don't worry about `Overall Bytes` but rather focus on `Live Bytes` and or `# Living`.

Comment: @Robert That link is saying what I was trying to say, that you don't just create it in `viewDidLoad` and expect it to clean up after itself. You must clean it up in `viewWillDisappear` (and, what that article says, but I didn't, that you would therefore probably want to create the timer in `viewDidAppear`). But the leak that article is concerned about (as was my answer) manifests itself _only when the view controller is dismissed._ You, on the other hand, were suggesting you had a leak when the view controller was created, and I'm suggesting you misinterpreted "overall bytes" as a leak.

Comment: I'm seeing this in the Leaks instruments.

Comment: Ah, i noticed the timer wasnt running at all so i deleted the link again :p now i have to try to find out how viewDidAppear works first.. and no, the objects CFArray (store-deque) and CFArray (mutable-variable) keeps increasing in size and after 30 min or so, my app uses like 1,5 GB of memory :o

Comment: I've been burned by this problem before.  Rob has hit the hammer on the head.  Repeating NSTimers and their targets will never be deallocated unless you call `invalidate` on the timer.

Comment: fixed. thanks rob! no more leaks. and you were also right about my misinterpretation of "overall bytes". its 6 am, dont blame me! :P